# Как запретить доступ к странице неавторизированным пользователям? php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

У меня есть страница (host/index.html) с окном авторизации и, если данные введены верно, то она переадресовывает пользователя на (host/forum/forum.html), но если пользователь просто отправит ссылку на host/forum/forum.html другу, и он перейдёт по ней, то он может не авторизироваться, и доступ к сайту будет.

Я читал про SESSION и COOKIE, но мне не очень понятно, что из этого выбрать и в какой части кода писать

Как проверять авторизовался пользователь и его перекинуло или он просто ввёл адрес страницы? И, если просто ввёл адрес страницы, то как его отбросить обратно на форму авторизации ?

**login.php :**

```
<?php
    include_once 'forum/getIp.php';

    $ip = getIp();
    $host = '';
    $userdb = '';
    $passdb = '';
    $db_name = '';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $userdb, $passdb, $db_name);

    $password_query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT pass FROM `users`');
    $login_query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT username FROM `users`');
    
    $password_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($password_query);
    $login_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($login_query);


    $password = $password_fetch['pass'];
    $login = $login_fetch['username'];
    

    $inputlogin = $_POST['login'];
    $inputpassword = $_POST['password'];

    if ($inputpassword == $password) {
        if ($inputlogin == $login) {
            $addip = "INSERT INTO users_ip (ip, username) VALUES('".$ip."', '".$login."')";
            mysqli_query($link, $addip);
            header('Location: forum/forum.html');
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }


    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
      <div class="panel" style="display: block;">
          <h1>Авторизация</h1>
          <input id="login" class="login" name="login" type="text" placeholder="Введите логин">
          <input id="password" name="password" class="password" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
          <button type="submit" name="button" class="loginButton">Авторизоваться</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: начните с сессии. Пишите туда какой-то признак при успешном входе в систему. На других страницах проверяйте наличие данного признака

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ предыдущего пользователя не будет корректно работать потому что это разные, если можно так выразится, сущности. `forum.html` - это уже представление, вывод данных, место где не нужна никакая логика регистрации, авторизации, выборки и тд. Почитайте про подход [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller).

Кроме того, метод из прошлого ответа будет плох при дальнейшем расширении функционала. Отдельным обработчиком авторизации не надо пренебрегать, потому что у вас уже есть запись `ip` пользователя, а если потребуется проверять ещё что-то? Например забанен ли пользователь? Расширять файл `login`, а не `forum`.

Дальше, действительно, с точки зрения выборки из MySQL лучше и быстрее будет использовать запрос с выбором пользователя на стороне MySQL, а для избежания SQL-инъекций [подготовленный](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) запрос или хотя бы экранировать символы перед проверкой, например [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (Внизу темы на сайте указано дополнительно несколько других функций).

После прохождения авторизации надо будет просто записать в сессию либо `id` пользователя, либо флаг, что он авторизован `login=true`.
Данный код нужно в ваш `login.php` поместить. Исправил Ваш:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'forum/getIp.php';
    $ip = getIp();
    $host = '';
    $userdb = '';
    $passdb = '';
    $db_name = '';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $userdb, $passdb, $db_name);
    $query = "SELECT id FROM `users` 
          WHERE `username` = '$inputlogin'
          AND `pass` = '$inputpassword'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(!empty($row['id']))
    {
        $addip = "INSERT INTO users_ip (ip, username) VALUES('".$ip."', '".$login."')";
        mysqli_query($link, $addip);
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header('Location: forum/forum.html');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Ну, а страницу с форумом переименовать в `forum.php` и перед выводом информации проверять через `empty`, ну либо `isset`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['login']))
{
    header('Location:index.html');
    exit;
}
?>
<!-- HTML -->
```

Comment: А нужно прописывать session_start() ? И куда мне вставлять первый код,, я попробовал вставить его в блок проверки введённых данных(if ($inputpassword == $password) { ...), но чето ничего не получилось, попробовал вписать этот блок в "//code", но тоже чтео ничего не получилось

Comment: @NastyStuffy да, запустить сессию надо, я думал она у вас включена. А код тогда скоро дополню подробностями в ответе

Comment: Оказывается нужно было просто вписать $_SESSION['login'] = true в моё условие, добавить везде session_start() и вписать нижний код  и всё))))

Comment: @NastyStuffy Ага, я также, почти, и дополнил ответ :)