# Как сделать проверку совпадение паролей form html в js

Tags: javascript, html, html5, html-form

Как сделать проверку совпадение паролей form html в js? Где я ввожу все, и по итогу проверит проверит совпадение двух паролей, при не совпадении вернет назад html экран и не отправит на БД?

Comment: Детализируйет ваш вопрос. Из него не понятно, что вам и где надо проврять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью js этого сделать нельзя, нужно работать с php.
создаёте php файл, в form указываете

```
<form method="post" action="(путь к файлу либо, если html лежит в проекте рядом с php файлом, то просто пишете название).php">
```

в самом .php файле подключаетесь к БД (в моём случае это MySQL)

```
$host = '';
$userdb = '';
$passdb = '';
$db_name = '';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $userdb, $passdb, $db_name);
```

далее мы получаем логин и пароль из базы

```
$password_query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT pass FROM `users`'); //здесь нужны ваши знания mysql 
$login_query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT username FROM `users`'); //здесь нужны ваши знания mysql чтобы получить данные из БД
    
$password_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($password_query);
$login_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($login_query);


$password = $password_fetch['pass'];
$login = $login_fetch['username'];
```

получаем введённые в форму данные

```
$inputlogin = $_POST['login'];
$inputpassword = $_POST['password'];
```

проверяем данные из формы с данными из БД

```
if ($inputpassword === $password) {
        if ($inputlogin === $login) {
            header('Location: '); //куда будет идти переадресация, если данные введены верно
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: index.html'); //(страница с формой авторизации) если введены неверно
        exit();
    }
```

так-же советую [почитать про $_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php), если хотите сделать форму авторизации, а ещё вот [пример использования сессий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462905/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-php)

Comment: Почему нельзя с помощью javaScript сравнить значения двух полей? И где в вопросе php? Вдруг бэкэнд на c#